# value is changed when select from DB

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

I have table in redshift data base. The table has column "PERCENTILE" defined as 
Type: float8 
Size: 17

I found that the value that I get different when run a select it as is or as a varchar.

```
select PERCENTILE , cast(PERCENTILE AS varchar) from ...
```

The result is:
0.156870898195838 | 0.15687089819583799

I do not know how to explain this. Is casting may change the value? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

When values appear different through typecasting, it is often an indication that your SQL client is applying some formatting or is somehow interpreting the results.

For example, some SQL clients display `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` values in the user's local timezone (as set on their computer). In such a case, doing `SELECT date, date::text` actually returns different values *within the client*, even though similar information is sent from Redshift.

In your situation, it appears that some rounding is taking place:

```
0.156870898195838
0.15687089819583799
```

The full value sent from Amazon Redshift is probably the 2nd value, but the client could be displaying the `float8` rounded to fewer decimal places.